# Apple In app purchase verify recurring payment in .NET Java 21002 exception

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

We are trying to verify a receipt for a RECURRING in-app payment made in iOS.

Referring to an earlier question on stack (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085847/keep-getting-21002-java-lang-nullpointerexception-on-apples-verifyreceipt), I manage to use the following code which sends in a JSON object made up of our receipt and sharedSecret key but we get the dreaded {"status":21002, "exception":"java.lang.NullPointerException"} error

```
Dim json As String ="{'receipt-data':'base64encoded receipt data','password':'YYYY'}"

Dim webRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt")
    webRequest.ContentType = "text/plain"
    webRequest.Method = "POST"
    Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)
    webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
    Using stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream()
        stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
        stream.Flush()
    End Using

    Dim resp = webRequest.GetResponse()
    If resp IsNot Nothing Then
        Using sr = New System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream())
            Dim result = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim()
            ' always getting '21002' 'java.lang.NullPointerException'

            Response.Write(result.ToString())
        End Using
    End If
```

Any help appreciated!